# Java return a value if null easy way - like in ruby nil || value return value

Tags: java, ruby

Is there a way in Java to easily check a null and return a default value?

In ruby we have:

```
nil || 100 # => evaluates to 100
nil || "Hello" # => evaluates to "Hello"
4   || 100 # => evaluates to 4
```

The easier way in Java I know is:

```
Double variable = null
variable != null ? variable : 100.0 # => evaluates to 100.0
variable != null ? variable : "Hello" # => evaluates to "Hello"
variable = 4.0
variable != null ? variable : 100.0 # => evaluates to 4.0
```

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Comment: Generally speaking you want to avoid using `null` and if you are doing this in lots of places in your code, you should rethink your design.

Comment: Unfortunately not (+1). Peter, can you elaborate? `null` seems to be perfectly fine for indicating "no value", just like `NULL` in SQL?

Comment: Peter, I quite understand what you mean. So +1. That would perfectly be a code smell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java8 has the support of `Optional`, using which we could do:

```
return Optional.ofNullable(variable).orElse(defaultValue);
```

Pre-Java8 versions don't include this class, however third-party libraries like [Guava, do](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Optional.html) provide similar types.

Comment: If you're mentioning Guava, it might be worth pointing out [`MoreObjects.firstNonNull`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/MoreObjects.html#firstNonNull(T,%20T))

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this infrequently, the ternary statement is not that bad.

If you need to do this often, just write a little method to wrap the ternary:

```
<T> T getOrDefault(T first, T second) {
  return first != null ? first : second;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
public static <T> T or(T... values) {
    for (T value : values)
        if (value != null)
            return value;
    return null;
}
```

and

```
System.out.println(or(null, 100));      // -> 100
System.out.println(or(null, "hello"));  // -> hello
System.out.println(or(4, 100));         // -> 4
System.out.println(or(null, null, null, "foo"));  // -> foo
```